# Global planner not updating path

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, global-planner, teb-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, ROS-kinetic to run the navigation stack (with global_planner and teb_local_planner) on a Youbot (on Gazebo).

Although I am able to send goals and get them executed properly, I have issues under the following scenario (configuration data follows):

When I add an obstacle(unmapped) into the environment(mapped), say blocking a certain path (alternative path available), and give a goal beyond the obstacle. I am running a rolling window for the local planner here, and the alternate path is not covered in the local costmap.

The issues I face:

Case 1: using obstacle layer in global costmap and local costmap: As soon as my laserscan detects the obstacle, marking of the global costmap starts and the planner issues a new global path upon sensing blocked path. Here, obviously the obstacle "avoidance" is being done by the global planner instead of the local planner.

Case 2: using obstacle layer only in the local costmap: The global costmap stays oblivious to the obstacle and upon reaching the blocked path, the local planner starts trying to look for alternative paths while the **global planner directs it to continue moving along this path**( since it is still unaware of obstacle). [Here, I believed that if unsuccessful in finding the path even after recovery behaviour, the global planner would issue a viable path. However, it never reaches even recovery stage as the local planner keeps probing the rolling window for trajectories.] As mentioned earlier, upon blocking this path, the alternative route is too far away to be included in the local costmap window [It achieves this when the window size is increased, but that takes up too much system processing for me to consider.] and the robot gets stuck.

Is it ok to stick with Case 1 and lower local planner's utility or Case 2 can be improved to cause global planner to take information from local costmap to replan when needed? or would some other plan of action be better?

I did read up similar questions like [this one here](https://answers.ros.org/question/62295/global-path-not-changing-despite-newly-discovered-obstacle/). However, increasing the planner frequency doesn't seem to have any effect as probably the global planner still does not consider the path blocked?

I also came across [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/261284/inform-move_base-about-blocked-plan/) which suggests that a 'false' returned from computeVelocityCommands from localplanner would force globalplanner to consider an alternative route? Considering this, is there a way to allow 'max_controller_retries' after which the local planner would give up and issue this 'False'?

Thanks

The configuration files:

---> **move_base_params**

```
oscillation_distance: 0.1
oscillation_timeout: 5.0
base_global_planner: "global_planner/GlobalPlanner"
planner_frequency: 10.0
planner_patience: 1.0

base_local_planner: "teb_local_planner/TebLocalPlannerROS"
controller_frequency: 10.0
controller_patience: 15.0


shutdown_costmaps: true
clearing_rotation_allowed: false

recovery_behaviours:  [{name: potential_field_recovery, type: potential_field_recovery/PotentialFieldRecovery},{name: aggressive_reset, type: clear_costmap_recovery/ClearCostmapRecovery}]
aggressive_reset:
  reset_distance: 0.5
  layer_names: ["obstacle_layer"]
```

--> **global_costmap_params** : set for Case1

```
global_costmap:

  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
  update_frequency: 4.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: true
  resolution: 0.05
  inflation_radius: 0.38
  cost_scaling_factor: 10.0

 
  transform_tolerance: 3.0
  plugins:
    - {name: static_layer,            type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    - {name: obstacle_layer,          type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
    - {name: inflation_layer,         type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

--> **local_costmap_params**

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: base_footprint
  update_frequency: 2.5
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 4.0
  height: 4.0
  resolution: 0.1

  transform_tolerance: 3.0

  
  plugins:
   - {name: static_layer,        type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
   - {name: obstacle_layer,      type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
```

--> **costmap_common_params**

```
footprint: [ [-0.3,-0.225], [0.3,-0.225], [0.3,0.225], [-0.3,0.225] ]

transform_tolerance: 0.2
map_type: costmap

obstacle_layer:
 enabled: true
 obstacle_range: 5.0
 raytrace_range: 5.5
 inflation_radius: 0.38
 track_unknown_space: false
 combination_method: 1

 observation_sources: base_scan

 base_scan: {sensor_frame: base_laser_front_link, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true, expected_update_rate: 0.5, observation_persistence: 0.0, min_obstacle_height: -0.10, max_obstacle_height: 2.0}

inflation_layer:
  enabled:              true
  cost_scaling_factor:  10.0  # exponential rate at which the obstacle cost drops off (default: 10)
  inflation_radius:     0.38  # max. distance from an obstacle at which costs are incurred for planning paths.

static_layer:
  enabled:              true
  map_topic:            "/map"
```

--> **teb_local_planner_params**

```
TebLocalPlannerROS:

 odom_topic: odom
  
 teb_autosize: True
 dt_ref: 0.3 #0.5
 dt_hysteresis: 0.1
 global_plan_overwrite_orientation: True
 global_plan_viapoint_sep: -0.1 #1.0
 max_global_plan_lookahead_dist: 3.0 #2
 feasibility_check_no_poses: 4 #2
 allow_init_with_backwards_motion: True
    
 # Robot
         
 max_vel_x: 0.8
 max_vel_y: 0.8
 max_vel_x_backwards: 0.8
 max_vel_theta: 1.2 # the angular velocity is also bounded by min_turning_radius in case of a carlike robot (r = v / omega)
 acc_lim_x: 1.25
 acc_lim_theta: 1.6

 # ********************** Carlike robot parameters ********************
 min_turning_radius: 0.0        # Min turning radius of the carlike robot (compute value using a model or adjust with rqt_reconfigure manually)

 footprint_model: # types: "point", "circular", "two_circles", "line", "polygon"
   type: "line"
   radius: 0.2 # for type "circular"
   line_start: [-0.168, 0.0] # for type "line"
   line_end: [0.168, 0.0] # for type "line"
   front_offset: 0.2 # for type "two_circles"
   front_radius: 0.2 # for type "two_circles"
   rear_offset: 0.2 # for type "two_circles"
   rear_radius: 0.2 # for type "two_circles"
   vertices: [ [0.25, -0.05], [0.18, -0.05], [0.18, -0.18], [-0.19, -0.18], [-0.25, 0], [-0.19, 0.18], [0.18, 0.18], [0.18, 0.05], [0.25, 0.05] ] # for type "polygon"

 # GoalTolerance
    
 xy_goal_tolerance: 0.15
 yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.1
 free_goal_vel: False
    
 # Obstacles
    
 min_obstacle_dist: 0.25 # This value must also include our robot's expansion, since footprint_model is set to "line".
 inflation_dist: 0.3
 dynamic_obstacle_inflation_distance: 0.4
 include_costmap_obstacles: True
 costmap_obstacles_behind_robot_dist: 2.0
 obstacle_poses_affected: 30
 costmap_converter_plugin: ""
 costmap_converter_spin_thread: True
 costmap_converter_rate: 5

 # Optimization
    
 no_inner_iterations: 3
 no_outer_iterations: 3
 optimization_activate: True
 optimization_verbose: False
 penalty_epsilon: 0.1
 weight_max_vel_x: 2
 weight_max_vel_theta: 1
 weight_acc_lim_x: 1
 weight_acc_lim_theta: 1
 weight_kinematics_nh: 0
 weight_kinematics_forward_drive: 0 #100 when obstacles
 weight_kinematics_turning_radius: 0
 weight_optimaltime: 1
 weight_obstacle: 50
 weight_dynamic_obstacle: 10 # not in use yet
 weight_viapoint: 5

 # Homotopy Class Planner

 enable_homotopy_class_planning: True
 enable_multithreading: True
 simple_exploration: False
 max_number_classes: 3
 selection_cost_hysteresis: 1.0
 selection_obst_cost_scale: 1.0
 selection_alternative_time_cost: False
 roadmap_graph_no_samples: 15
 roadmap_graph_area_width: 5
 h_signature_prescaler: 0.5
 h_signature_threshold: 0.1
 obstacle_keypoint_offset: 0.1
 obstacle_heading_threshold: 0.45
 visualize_hc_graph: False
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284424/global-planner-not-updating-path/) by [harshal](https://answers.ros.org/users/32094/harshal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-03-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tropic](https://answers.ros.org/users/3186/tropic/) on 2020-10-24**:
Hi. Did you find a proper setup to have the global planner take the blocked path into consideration? I have tried very similar settings as yours, but it does not work as intended, especially the static layers for the local costmap makes the costmap non-functional.

**Comment by [harshal](https://answers.ros.org/users/32094/harshal/) on 2020-10-30**:
Hi, I carried on with keeping the obstacle layer in the global costmap as well. Turning the global planner frequency to 0.0 makes the planner use only the data available at plan time, and lets the local planner carry on the "dynamic" obstacle avoidance for anything not reflected in the initial plan. As for the local planner, I let the local planner fail after some tries and this triggers the global planner to plan around the obstacles sanely.

I do still have the static layer in my current local costmap setup (needed). Could you elaborate as to what a non-functional costmap means in your case?

P.S.: This strategy is likely to fail for larger obstacles. Depending upon your configuration, the local planner might continuously keep trying to look for new paths. So if you have a local planner struggling unrelentingly(no timeouts or max no. of attempts, etc.) to go around bigger map changes/obstacles, a non-zero rate of global planning might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The behaviour you are describing is what I would expect for the given config.

As long as you do not use the obstacles layer with the global costmap, it has no way in knowing the current path is not feasible. Even if you trigger recovery behaviors, the map will be pretty much the same, so the global plan is unlikely to change.

**"Is it ok to stick with Case 1 and lower local planner's utility or Case 2 can be improved to cause global planner to take information from local costmap to replan when needed? or would some other plan of action be better?"**

Yes, it is ok to use Case 1. If you want to "increase the utility" of your local planner, you can try to reduce the global planner frequency (but with obstacles layer active) to something like 0.1Hz, so you will allow the local to try to find an alternative, before replanning the global path.

It is hard to envision any improvements in case 2. What you are proposing pretty much falls into activating the obstacle layer in global costmap. The best I can think of is writing an external node that activate or deactivate the obstacle layer in global costmap according to some info from your local planner. But I do not see the advantage on that.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2018-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harshal](https://answers.ros.org/users/32094/harshal/) on 2018-03-06**:
Hi,
Thank you for the answer. I had just been testing setting planner frequency to (actually) 0.1 Hz. Actually if the obstacle is detected in the 10th second or so, it amounts to case1 itself & of course there is no way of controlling the detection! But still worth the change, I believe!

**Comment by [harshal](https://answers.ros.org/users/32094/harshal/) on 2018-03-06**:
And I had not thought about the fact that even after recovery, map remain the same (original), so nothing should prompt the global planner to change path!!